# Getting the sum of values from Checkboxes and Selects - KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I already made this in jQuery: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm7488/71q6e4z0/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
         <h3>Crazy Sh*t we'll do for Money</h3>

        <div class="small"><em>An elegant way to test out Knockout JS you're thinking of doing</em>

        </div>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="150" id="srv" />
            <span>Throw knives at us while we're strapped on a turn table ($150)</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="200" id="srv" />
            <span>Watch us get chased by Bulls ($200)</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="799.50" id="srv" />
            <span>Watch us in a straight jacket immersed in a pool of electric Eels and try to get out of it Houdini style. ($799.50)</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
    <div class="marginise">
<strong>I want to donate to your hospital bills</strong>

        <select id="donate" name="donate">
            <option value="0">No Thanks</option>
            <option value="100">$100</option>
            <option value="300">$300</option>
            <option value="500">$500</option>
        </select>
        <p><strong>Donations</strong>: <span id="blah"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="est">
         <h4>Total</h4>
 <span id="serviceTotal"> </span>

    </div>
    <div class="f">These Events / Entertainment Services are not real. Unfortunately.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function outputValue() {
    mathUsage();
    var donValues = $("#donate").val(); //take from Select
    $("#blah").html(numeral(donValues).format('$0,0[.]00'));
}
var $cap = $('input[name="services"]'); //set VAR for checkbox values

function mathUsage() {
    var total = $("#donate").val(); // total (0) + donate value
    $cap.each(function () {
        if (this.checked) total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $("#serviceTotal").text(numeral(total).format('$0,0[.]00'));
}
//NumeralJS -> numeral(1000).format('0,0');

$("select").change(outputValue);
outputValue();

$cap.click(mathUsage);

//Now... how to Knockout? :/
```

What I'm trying to practice on is to create it in knockoutJS so I can have a smaller set of HTML markup.

What is the best way to go with this?

I know there are tons of clues out there, like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/G2hxP/) that outputs the values of check-boxes in an Array... I was thinking to use the same method and set the values to a sum, but no idea how to start or what syntax should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give each checkbox it's own id/name first of all:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="knives" value="150" id="knives" data-bind="checked: knives" />
            <span>Throw knives at us while we're strapped on a turn table ($150)</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="bulls" value="200" id="bulls" data-bind="checked: bulls"  />
            <span>Watch us get chased by Bulls ($200)</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="eels" value="799.50" id="eels" data-bind="checked: eels" />
            <span>Watch us in a straight jacket immersed in a pool of electric Eels and try to get out of it Houdini style. ($799.50)</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then your view model as such is this:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.knives = ko.observable(false);
    self.bulls = ko.observable(false);
    self.eels= ko.observable(false);

    self.total = ko.computed(function() {
      var i = 0;
      if (self.knives())
        i += 150;
      if (self.bulls())
        i += 200;
      if (self.eels())
        i += 799.50;    
      return total; 
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

That's the general idea. You can add other viewModel properties to hold the values for each service, or make a little object to contain the value and state for each 'service'. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like following:

```js
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.first = ko.observable(first);
    this.last = ko.observable(last);
 
    this.total = ko.computed(function() {
        
        return parseFloat(this.first())  + parseFloat(this.last());
    }, this);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("10", "10"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>First: <input data-bind='value: first' /></p> 
    <p>Last: <input data-bind='value: last' /></p> 
    <h2> <span data-bind='text: total'> </span></h2>  
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23633/)

Comment: A vague one but it helps!  I'll come back with progress.